# How do you add the "Reports.Read.All" permission so you can use the Graph explorer to run the Office 365 usage reports?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the graph explorer to access the beta Office 365 usage reports. I can see that these report require the "Reports.Read.All" permission and I'm seeing that the account I'm using doesn't have that permission yet, but when I click on the "Modify your permissions" link it doesn't display this permission. How do you add this permission to an account, so that you can use the graph explorer with this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reports.read.all` permission has been added to the Graph Explorer code repository at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/commit/093600ec7bc7bd32befe5d118270ea71ca8008b4 and will be deployed to our website in the next update. We're working on a process to get new scopes added to the explorer automatically so we don't have this delay in the future.

Comment: so where do you add that in the permissions tool in azure ad?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an administrator to be able to consent to that permission scope